# Simple LinearRegression applied to multiple entries of data (not Multiple Linear Regression)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I need to perform the following computations.

1. A given *Nx1* pandas dataframe
2. Conversion of the dataframe in Numpy matrix (it would be the Y variable of the regression)
3. Conversion of the shifted (by 1) dataframe in Numpy matrix (it would be the X variable of the regression)
4. Performing simple linear regression between X and Y
5. Using the linear regression coefficient (*1x1* array) compute a new Numpy matrix *Nx1* as `(1/1-coefficient)*(Y.T) - (coefficient/1-coefficient)*(X.T)`
6. Convert the result to a *Nx1* pandas dataframe

Please consider the following code:

```
def function(data):

        Y = np.nan_to_num(np.asmatrix(data)).T
        X = np.nan_to_num(np.asmatrix(data.shift(1))).T
        
        M = lm.LinearRegression().fit(X, Y)
    
        result = (np.dot((1/1-M.coef_), Y.T)) - (np.dot(M.coef_ / 1-M.coef_, X.T))
        
        return pd.DataFrame(result.T, columns = data.columns, index = data.index)
```

How can I perform efficiently (it would be much better avoiding `for` cycle) the same process when the given pandas dataframe is *NxM*? In this case the array of regression coefficients would be *1xM* with each column being the coefficient between the i-column of X and the i-column of Y.